# <p> tag does not start on new line

Tags: html, css

after "Automotive" tag the "p" tag doesn't start on a new line but instead is on the same line as the "h3" tag same thing happens after the phone tag and email tag, it happens in chrome and other browsers however it all works fine in safari.
html:

```
<div id="detailsm">
<h2>Contact Info</h2>
<h3>Automotive</h3>
<p>ccdccdc cascara</p>
<p>here</p> 
<p>left 0110</p>
<h3>Phone</h3>
<p>03 022 0221</p>
<p>03 022 8888</p>
<p>03 322 1022</p>
<h3>Email</h3>
<p>sacascasc@gmail.com</p>
</div>
```

css:

```
#detailsm{
    padding: 30px 0 0 100px;
}

#detailsm h3{
    float: center;
    color: #696969;
}
```

Comment: That Google Chrome tag doesn't apply to this question.

Comment: it's producing a newline, to test that please put **display:inline;**  ,you can see the difference

Comment: This is what i get when i tried display:inline;

Comment: https://postimg.org/image/w1shco9ax/

Answer (score 0):

don't use float property. If you want your  in center. try text-align property:

```
#detailsm h3{
    text-align: center;
    color: #696969;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`float:center;` Really?

It works fine now if this is what you want.

```css
    #detailsm{
        padding: 30px 0 0 100px;
    }
    
    #detailsm h3{
        text-align: center;
        color: #696969;
    }
```

```html
    It's working fine.
    
    <div id="detailsm">
    <h2>Contact Info</h2>
    <h3>Automotive</h3>
    <p>ccdccdc cascara</p>
    <p>here</p> 
    <p>left 0110</p>
    <h3>Phone</h3>
    <p>03 022 0221</p>
    <p>03 022 8888</p>
    <p>03 322 1022</p>
    <h3>Email</h3>
    <p>sacascasc@gmail.com</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: [link](https://postimg.org/image/4hnovu8jz/) thats how i want it to look and thats how it looks in safari  but when u tried what you said it looks like this [link](https://postimg.org/image/f2ghxv39p/)

Comment: @esim could you also attach a screenshot of this in safari and chrome?

Also could you post your entire code for this?